# Firebase web app - can't get user.uid when creating new account

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a small web app and I have hit a roadblock that I can't seem to overcome. I am able to register a new account, but I would like to save additional data to a database right after signing up.

This is what I have that I am confident that works fine.

```js
$("#user-sign-up-button").click(function(){


  var firstName = $("#new-user-first-name").val();
  var secondName = $("#new-user-surname").val();
  var charity = $("#new-user-charity-account").val();
  var userEmail = $("#new-user-email").val();
  var userPassword = $("#new-user-password").val();
  var secondPassword = $("#new-user-repeated").val();

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
  
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
  });


});
```

Now in regards to saving the additional variables to the database I have tried both of the below within .then part of createuserWithEmailAndPassword.

```js
.then(
    function(user){
      var root = firebase.database().ref();
      var uid = user.uid;
      alert(uid);
      var postData = {  firstName: first_name,
        secondName: second_name,
        email: user_email,
        isCharity: charity };
        root.child("users").child(uid).set(postData);
    }

    function writeUserData(first_name, second_name, charity, user_email) {
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
        firstName: first_name,
        secondName: second_name,
        email: user_email,
        isCharity: charity
    });
  )
```

Both of the above solutions work within onAuthStateChanged but I want to capture the data at sign up, not every time someone signs in.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: _"I have tried both of the below within .then part of createuserWithEmailAndPassword."_ Is it me or didn't you add that part of the code in your question? I only see the catch error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `.onAuthStateChanged` to get at `firebase.auth().currentUser`. It's asynchronous and will be empty/`null` until it resolves. Also, don't forget that new email based accounts will not be `.emailValidated:true` until they have clicked a verification email link. ...something to consider.

Comment: If I do use onAuthStateChanged, would the information be resubmitted every time someone logs in it would check to add this data to a database? Because that seems excessive, and somewhat wrong to have it there haha.

Comment: "For a web application, the default behavior is to persist a user's session even after the user closes the browser." [source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)